# Find what 2 numbers add to something and multiply to something

Tags: php, numbers, factoring

Hey so I'm making a factoring program and I'm wondering if anyone can give me any ideas on an efficient way to find what two numbers multiple to a specified number, and also add to a specified number.

for example I may have

(a)(b) = 6

a + b = 5

So essentially i just need a way to find the a and b values. In this case they would be 2 and 3.

Can anyone give me any ideas on where to start? Negative numbers must also be considered for use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to loop, just use simple math to solve this equation system:

a*b = i;

a+b = j;

a = j/b;

a = i-b;

j/b = i-b; so:

b + j/b + i = 0

**b^2 + i*b + j = 0**

From here, its a quadratic equation, and it's trivial to find **b** (just implement the [quadratic equation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula)) and from there get the value for **a**.

There you go:

```
function finder($add,$product)
{

 $inside_root = $add*$add - 4*$product;

 if($inside_root >=0)
 {

     $b = ($add + sqrt($inside_root))/2;
     $a = $add - $b;

     echo "$a+$b = $add and $a*$b=$product\n";

 }else
 {
   echo "No real solution\n";
 }
}
```

Real live action:

http://codepad.org/JBxMgHBd

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do that:

```
$sum = 5;
$product = 6;

$found = FALSE;
for ($a = 1; $a < $sum; $a++) {
  $b = $sum - $a;
  if ($a * $b == $product) {
    $found = TRUE;
    break;
  }
}

if ($found) {
  echo "The answer is a = $a, b = $b.";
} else {
  echo "There is no answer where a and b are both integers.";
}
```

Basically, start at `$a = 1` and `$b = $sum - $a`, step through it one at a time since we know then that `$a + $b == $sum` is always true, and multiply `$a` and `$b` to see if they equal `$product`. If they do, that's the answer.

[See it working](http://codepad.org/LSgMM57G)

Whether that is the *most efficient* method is very much debatable.

Answer (score 2):

With the multiplication, I recommend using the modulo operator (%) to determine which numbers divide evenly into the target number like:

```
$factors = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $target; $i++){
    if($target % $i == 0){
        $temp = array()
        $a = $i;
        $b = $target / $i;
        $temp["a"] = $a;
        $temp["b"] = $b;
        $temp["index"] = $i;
        array_push($factors, $temp);
    }
}
```

This would leave you with an array of factors of the target number.

Answer (score 1):

That's basically a set of 2 [simultaneous equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations):

```
x*y = a
X+y = b
```

(using the mathematical convention of x and y for the variables to solve and a and b for arbitrary constants).

But the solution involves a quadratic equation (because of the x*y), so depending on the actual values of a and b, there may not be a solution, or there may be multiple solutions.